# Listing of $S_3$ for roots of $x^3 -3x+1=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra

*Request help in vetting my understanding of the text 'Abstract Algebra', by Beachy, Blair, on pg. #86; as stated below. Also, please guide for goading for more details, if correct.:*

It talks about eqn. $x^3-3x+1=0$ (solved by trigonometrical substitution $\cos(3\theta)= \cos(\theta+2\theta)$ in sec. 6.3.8 Lemma), and lists the $6= 3!$ possible orderings (permutations) of three roots $r_1, r_2, r_3$.

I am having trouble understanding why the names of the permutations are given as : 
$(1)$,
$(1,2,3)$ ,
$(1,3,2)$ ,
$(2,3)$ ,
$(1,3)$ ,
$(1,2)$

It tried to look for the reason, as by me it is axiomatic (*i.e., no further reason can be ascribed to it*) to have the different elements of the group defined by $S_3$; as per its defn. [from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group): 
 $S_3$ is defined over $3$ set elements, let $(1 2 3)$ with $S_3$ group elements as the bijections (permutations, rearrangements) from the set to itself, and whose group operation is the composition of functions.

Simplest of the group is the identity element, denoted by $(1)$:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Next is the element denoted by $(2 3)$:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & 3 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Third is the element denoted by $(1 3)$:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Fourth is the element denoted by $(1 2)$:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 1 & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
Fifth is the element denoted by $(1 2 3)$:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 3 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
Sixth (last) is the element denoted by $(1 3 2)$:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    3 & 1 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

The reason why a particular ordering of roots is ascribed to a given element of $S_3$ is given by **Cayley's theorem**, that states : Every finite group $G$ of order $n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric groups $S_n$.

So, the corresponding permutations of 3 roots $r_1, r_2, r_3$ are given corresponding names of the compositions of $S_3$.

[image]

Comment: The image is illegible.  Is it necessary to your question, or the demonstration of your work?  Perhaps you can cite the page, and type out the question?

Comment: @amWhy If you please open it on another tab (by right clicking on the image), then it is clear. Yes, it shows why I was confused, as no reason as to the link with permutations of $S_3$, or Cayley's theorem, or even a set of compositions of $S_3$ was shown in the book.

Comment: I am not sure what your Q is, or what it is that you don't understand, but I'd be glad to help.